# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.Linq.Binary in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, hash

I've hashed the password and then I'll insert it to the database but the problem here is that
each time I try to do this query this occurs

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.Linq.Binary'
```

in my table in the database accnt_pass is Binary(50), here's my code

```
//Instantiate a new Hasher Object
var hasher = new Hasher();

hasher.SaltSize = 16;

//Encrypts The password
var encryptedPassword = hasher.Encrypt(txtPass.Text);

Account newUser = new Account();

newUser.accnt_User = txtUser.Text;
newUser.accnt_Position = txtPosition.Text;
newUser.accnt_Pass = encryptedPassword;
```

and I am using Encrypto for hashing,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert the string encryptedPassword to a byte array if your sql column is of binary type.
So instead of the line

```
newUser.accnt_Pass = encryptedPassword;
```

put

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
newUser.accnt_Pass = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(encoding.GetBytes(encryptedPassword));
```

Comment: R after that? can I directly insert it on my table?

Comment: Okay thank you, by the way, How come when I inserted the same password on different accounts(for testing puposes) they both have differentt values? how will I know if the one typed is the same as the one in the database?

Comment: I think you should ask this as a separate question and tag it with Encrypto so that people who are familiar with this utility can help. But I can make an educated guess that generating different hashes for the same password is point of salted hashes.